# Ruby on Rails: a weird no method error in my controller?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's what I got in my logs:

Started POST "/video_votes.437?type=up" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 18 01:11:14 -0700 2011
  Processing by VideoVotesController#create as 
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"DLyDcc4MJxK7gk4URiyyjvsLLl9hjtDChAyQRGVawKg=", "type"=>"up"}
Completed   in 83ms

NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):
  app/controllers/video_votes_controller.rb:3:in `create'

I get this error when I click the button that calls on the create method.

Here's the code in my create method (note that line three is the `@video = Video.find(params[:video_vote][:video_id])` line):

```
def create       
  @video = Video.find(params[:video_vote][:video_id])
  @vote = @video.video_votes.new
  if params[:type] = "up"
    @vote.value = 1
  else
    @vote.value = -1
  end

  if @vote.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @video }
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @video }
      format.js {render 'fail_create.js.erb'}
    end
  end
```

And here's my code for the button in my view that calls the create method:

```
<div id='voting_div'>
  <%= button_to "+1", video_votes_path(video, :type=> "up"), :remote => true %>
  <div id='vote_display'>
    <p id='votes'><%= pluralize video.vote_sum, 'Votes' %></p>
  </div>
  <%= button_to "-1", video_votes_path(video, :type=> "down"), :remote => true %>
</div>
```

What's going on here? How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You params hash is 
 `{"authenticity_token"=>"DLyDcc4MJxK7gk4URiyyjvsLLl9hjtDChAyQRGVawKg=", "type"=>"up"}`

In this hash there is no key called "video_vote" , so when you try to access `params[:video_vote][:video_id]`, because  `params[:video_vote]` is nil. it will throw this error.

Check your routes or if you need to "GET" more values with the button, because your  **params** hash doesn't know about the "video_vote" key.

Comment: yeah really good point. I have this line in my routes: `resources :video_votes` so I'm not sure why params doesn't know of it...

Comment: Oh, could it be that I only have a create method and not a new method?

Comment: can you post the "complete" controller code, and exactly what you are trying to do :) .

Comment: well the create method is actually the only thing in the video_votes controller, so that may be where I'm going wrong. It's a simple up/down voting mechanism where when you click the button, it calls the create method and saves the vote in the database. Then I update the total vote count with ajax (kind of unrelated to this error).